# wanted to update target coloum with source table and where condition with two coloumn

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

1. Not able to update target table.
2. Using where condition from both table ac_no and part_no column should be match.
3. I tried this code but when I execute in actionoutput shown only
   running

Please help me determine where my code does not work

```
UPDATE 
    wo.rr_sec
INNER JOIN 
    wo.rb_acpt ON 
    rr_sec.AC_NO = wo.rb_acpt.ac_no
SET 
    wo.rr_sec.p_name = wo.rb_acparts.p_name
WHERE
    wo.rr_sec.AC_NO=wo.rb_acpt.ac_no and
    wo.rr_sec.PART_NO=wo.rr_acparts.part_no;
```

Comment: mysql <> sql-server. Use explicit joins.

Comment: could you edit this code with right way using explicit joins .thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I assume you want something similar to:

```
UPDATE 
    wo.rr_sec
SET 
    wo.rr_sec.p_name = wo.rb_acparts.p_name
FROM 
    wo.rr_sec
INNER JOIN 
    wo.rb_acpt ON 
    wo.rr_sec.AC_NO = wo.rb_acpt.ac_no
INNER JOIN
    wo.rr_acparts ON
    wo.rr_sec.PART_NO=wo.rr_acparts.part_no;
```